# Conversion of PHP Curl into Bash Curl Issue

Tags: bash, curl

Here is the CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT from PHP Curl Call-

```
"GET \/api\/v2\/file\/upload?token=c3344fd7d60f3e6587308f55e3aed0f7&name=Client3.php&hash=ccb1fac3110514a2039b5da707717f81&size=15390 HTTP\/1.1\r\nHost: rapidgator.net\r\nAccept: *\/*\r\n\r\n"
```

Now how can I change this into Bash Curl to upload a file?

My attempt is-

```
FileUploadResponse=$(curl -H "CURLOPT_HEADER:false" -H "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER:true" "$BaseURL"'file/upload?token='"$Token"'&hash='"$Hash"'&size='"$FileSize"'&name='"$FileName"|grep -E 'response')
echo $FileUploadResponse
```

Comment: Why do you keep switching from single to double quotes, instead of just putting the entire argument in double quotes?

Comment: `CURLOPT_HEADER` and `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` are not HTTP headers.

Comment: Can you please make an example?

Comment: Like this: `"${baseURL}file/upload?token=$Token&hash=$Hash"`

Comment: My Bash Curl Call may not reflect the PHP Curl Call.

Comment: You can't use a `GET` request to upload a file, it has to be a `POST`.

Comment: Here is my Bash Script- https://github.com/observo/Bash/blob/master/UploadFinal.sh